# How can I run code locally with dependencies and exclude them when creating a Jar with Maven

Tags: java, scala, maven, apache-spark

I'm new to this so might sound silly. I'm writing Scala Spark code on my local machine and then upload it to a cluster for execution (test environment).
My issue is that I don't want to include Spark dependencies when creating a Jar as they are present on the cluster. But to run the code locally I need them.
So far I have tried to provide scope as provided

```
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

This allows me to exclude dependencies from Jar but when I run it locally i need to delete the scope. I looked at other scope options but I couldn't find one that would work for me.
What am I missing?

Comment: Why would you have to remove the scope locally? You can resolve the scope from env variable (defaulting to provided), with `runtime` or `compile` scope locally

Comment: @cchantep can you please explain in more detail what you said. I have to remove scope so that I can run code locally. How would you override provided?

Comment: `<scope>${spark.dependencyScope}</scope>` => `mvn -Dspark.dependencyScope=..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use different [maven profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

Something like this would help you:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        …
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        …
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>debug</id>
        …
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        …
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then you can run `test` profile on remote and `debug` profile for your local run.

Comment: To choose the profile use -P when building the jar: mvn clean install -P debug

Comment: is this possible with gradle?